# Background color of the graph affects the other graphs too

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs, react-chartjs-2

The graph under App.js has a background color. The problem is, the background color also takes effect in the other graph from another component. How can I fix this where only the graph from App.js has the background color. I have recreated this in codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/color-the-canvas-fec5y?file=/src/App.js

This is what I've used to color the background of the graph:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    Chart.register({
      id: "custom_canvas_background_color",
      beforeDraw: (chart) => {
        const ctx = chart.canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.save();
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";
        ctx.fillStyle = "lightblue";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, chart.width, chart.height);
        ctx.restore();
      }
    });
  }, []);
```

Comment: Instead of coloring the canvas, apply the background color to the div that's wrapping it.

Comment: @ChrisG Reason you wouldnt want to do it with CSS is, if you want to print/save the chart. In that case the CSS background isnt taken with it so you have a transparent background.

Comment: @LeeLenalee That's just a browser print setting though, it's perfectly possible to print the page as it appears on screen

Comment: @ChrisG Not if you just want the canvas, if you get the base64 string from the canvas to save the chart as an image for example you dont get the background set by CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Alexandre pointed out with `Chart.register` your plugin gets registered globally to all your charts and since you hardcode a backgroundColor it will apply to all the charts. You can either only register it locally to the single chart instance as Alexandre suggested.

The other better approach is to make the backgroundColor a variable that you can set in your options. First you can check if it is set, if not you dont draw anything and if its set you can have a different color on different charts:

```js
Chart.register({
  id: "custom_canvas_background_color",
  beforeDraw: (chart, args, opts) => {
    if (!opts.color) {
      return
    }

    const ctx = chart.canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.save();
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";
    ctx.fillStyle = opts.color;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, chart.width, chart.height);
    ctx.restore();
  }
});

const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      borderColor: 'pink'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      custom_canvas_background_color: {
        color: 'lightblue'
      }
    }
  }
}

const options2 = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      borderColor: 'orange'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      custom_canvas_background_color: {
        color: 'pink'
      }
    }
  }
}

const options3 = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      borderColor: 'lightblue'
    }]
  },
  options: {}
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
const ctx2 = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer2').getContext('2d');
const ctx3 = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer3').getContext('2d');

new Chart(ctx, options);
new Chart(ctx2, options2);
new Chart(ctx3, options3);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer2" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer3" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/color-the-canvas-forked-90qiv?file=/src/Graph2.js)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [chart.js plugins documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#global-plugins), using `Chart.register` registers the plugin globally and applies it to all charts. Instead, store the plugin in a variable

```
const plugin = {
    id: "custom_canvas_background_color",
    beforeDraw: (chart) => {
      const ctx = chart.canvas.getContext("2d");
      ctx.save();
      ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";
      ctx.fillStyle = "lightBlue";
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, chart.width, chart.height);
      ctx.restore();
    }
  };
```

And pass it as a props to the Line component like this:

```
<Line
  plugins={[plugin]}
/>
```

Comment: As @LeeLenalee said, you can add options to make your plugin more flexible